# Prevent shutdown until ExecStop script completes

Tags: centos7, systemd

I have a script that runs infinitely at startup, and another script that shuts it down safely.  The second script requires connection to a remote database.  They are both declared in the same service as `ExecStart` and `ExecStop` respectively.  I need the second script to block shutdown/reboot until it completes.  Currently the first script works fine but the second script is terminated early.  Here is what I have so far:

```
[Unit]
DefaultDependencies=no
Wants=network-online.target
After=network.target network-online.target
Before=reboot.target shutdown.target halt.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
User=test
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/test/test.py
ExecStop=/usr/bin/sh /home/test/test
KillMode=none

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I tried using the following: [systemd to wait for command to complete before restart/shutdown or killing other processes](https://serverfault.com/questions/519029/systemd-to-wait-for-command-to-complete-before-restart-shutdown-or-killing-other) but it did not solve my problem, and it seems like his are commands that run relatively quickly.

Comment: You say you have a script that runs infinitely - you refer to the python script `/home/test/test.py` here? If it does indeed run infinitely (does not terminate) then I'd question the use of Type=oneshot here, which in turn, and in conjunction with the RemainAfterExit=true directive may influence the behaviour of the ExecStop command you are experiencing.

Comment: @Benjamin It didn't make a difference for the problem I was trying to solve, but you're right, it doesn't make sense to make it a oneshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the following and it worked:

```
TimeoutSec=300min
```

My final configuration is:

```
[Unit]
DefaultDependencies=no
Wants=network-online.target
After=network.target network-online.target
Before=reboot.target shutdown.target halt.target

[Service]
Type=simple
RemainAfterExit=true
User=test
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/test/test.py
ExecStop=/usr/bin/sh /home/test/test
KillMode=none
TimeoutSec=300min

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Note**: I purposely did not make the `TimeoutSec=infinity`