# Behaviour of systemd services on reboot

Tags: systemd, systemctl

On a Debian 8 I have deployed an application of mine that consists of several smaller apps and one of those smaller ones uses a [HDF5](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/) file. The problem with `HDF5` files is that you **have** to close them. If for example you program chrases or your program get killed, the `HDF5` files get corrupted. Depending on the size of the `HDF5` file, closing it can take several seconds.

I have a tool `mondas_ctrl` which is a manager of my applications, their structure is not important here. When logged in (over ssh) I can execute `mondas_ctrl start` or `mondas_ctrl stop` without a problem, specially the *stop* command knows how to deal with the `HDF5` files (by adding delays inbetween).

With the old SysV I was able to delay the halt process by changing the runlevel 6 on `/etc/inittab` wth a self written script that took care of the HDF5 files before doing `init 0`. Now `systemd` is default and I had to change the way I think of `init.d` files and services. So I wrote an user service that uses my manager to start and stop my apps:

File: `~/.config/systemd/user/mondas.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Mondas

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/home/mondas/anaconda/default/bin/mondas_ctrl start
ExecRestart=/home/mondas/anaconda/default/bin/mondas_ctrl restart
ExecStop=/home/mondas/anaconda/default/bin/mondas_ctrl stop
KillMode=none

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

At first I had a little bit of trouble with the *stop* command. After [reading this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/519029/systemd-to-wait-for-command-to-complete-before-restart-shutdown-or-killing-other) I added the `Type`, `RemainAfterExit` and `KillMode` options. These helped a lot and now I can do this:

```
$ systemctl --user start mondas
$ systemctl --user stop mondas
$ systemctl --user start mondas
```

as many times as I want, the *stop* command doesn't kill anything, my `mondas_ctrl` manager stops the `HDF5` app, the file is closed and doesn't get corrupted.

But when I do a system wide reboot (either by executing `reboot` or `shutdown -r now`), the `KillMode` flag seems to be ignored or the whole service seems to be skipped, the logs on screen pass by so quick, I cannot tell if my service is executed at all.

So the question is, do "stop" services behave differently when you execute `systemctl stop` and when you execute `reboot/shutdown -r now`? If so, what do I have to do during reboot so that my app has enough time to close the `HDF5` file?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is a great answer on the unix.stackexchange that I recommand you to read to fully understand how systemd works, and how to solve your issue. You can find it here : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211924/effect-of-reboot-signal-on-systemd-service-state

Hope this can help you !